# Javascript stylesheet switcher

Tags: javascript, css, browser-detection

Excuse me if this question has been answered I have looked and seen things that come some what close but don't really solve my problem.

What I want to do is use a short JavaScript code to switch from one stylesheet to another depending on the browser the viewer is using.

Answer (score -1):

How about this one?

http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml

There are similar articles with keywords, css javascript switcher

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. I'll read what the article has to say on the subject. in the mean  i solved my problem by taking a bit of code someone on here wrote to detect the browser type and version, and modified it to write in the style sheet link based on the result. lol.